# How to use a div tag to create a layout and make it responsive

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

Hi I have tried craeting a layout below

[image]

I have created using a table tag. But the layout is not responsive . I want to use the div tag but i do not know how to do it? I'm placing react component inside those layouts.

Any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: can you please share your code which you have tried to achieve this layout?

Comment: What have you already tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: This should help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Mastering_Wrapping_of_Flex_Items

Comment: @BenM The component are not responsive

Comment: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Help by voting and accepting answer if its work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, if you do it without fancy flexbox stuff:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="inner-top"></div>
    <div class="inner-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left .inner-top {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.left .inner-bottom {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/leo-melin/pen/WNboeBb

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>A Three Items Grid Layout:</h1>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item item1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item item2">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item item3">3</div>  
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]